# How can I create a 'while'-exception loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, exception

I am working on a small coding challenge which takes user input. This input should be checked to be a digit. I created a "try: ... except ValueError: ..." block which checks once whether the input is a digit but not multiple times. I would like it to basically checking it continuously.

**Can one create a while-exception loop?**

My code is the following:

```
try:
    uinput = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

    while uinput <= 0:
        uinput = int(input("Number is negative. Please try again: "))
    else:
        for i in range(2, uinput):
            if (uinput % i == 0):
                print("Your number is a composite number with more than
                       one divisors other than itself and one.")
                break
            else:
                print(uinput, "is a prime number!")
                break

except ValueError:
    uinput = int(input("You entered not a digit. Please try again: "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flag = True
while flag:
    try:
        uinput = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

        while uinput <= 0:
            uinput = int(input("Number is negative. Please try again: "))
        else:
            flag=False
            for i in range(2, uinput):
                if (uinput % i == 0):
                    print("Your number is a composite number with more than one divisors other than itself and one.")
                    break
                else:
                    print(uinput, "is a prime number!")
                    break

    except ValueError:
        print('Wrong input')
```

**Output :**

```
(python37) C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
Please enter a number: qwqe
Wrong input
Please enter a number: -123
Number is negative. Please try again: 123
123 is a prime number!
```

I add flag boolean to not make it repeat even when the input is correct and deleted input in except because it would ask 2 times.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It solved my question! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you press Enter only, the loop terminated:

```
while True:

    uinput = input("Please enter a number: ")
    if uinput.strip()=="":
        break
    try:
        uinput=int(uinput)    
    except:
        print("You entered not a digit. Please try again")
        continue

    if uinput<=0:
        print("Not a positive number. Please try again")
        continue

    for i in range(2, uinput):
            pass; # put your code here
```